# Netbeans Lowercase Shortcut Not Working

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-8

Netbeans has a [nice set of keyboard shortcuts](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf), but unfortunately, I can't seem to get all of them to work. Specifically, there's a keyboard shortcut for converting selected text to lowercase: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>. However, no matter how many times I try this (or variations on it), <s>nothing happens</s> I just get a 'ding' sound (it used to be that nothing happened). I check the Keymap option on Netbeans, and it shows that this is still the shortcut mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I use this keyboard shortcut?

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> works just fine, among many other shortcuts.

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To activate this shortcut you have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then hit <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I wish they wrote it as `(Ctrl + U) (L)`

Comment: And the award for Most Idiotic Lowercase Shortcut goes to... NETBEANS!

Answer (score 10):

It's like saying Ortomala Lokni

- to uppercase a selection, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Let me add also:

- to lowercase a selection, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd> without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- to reverse case in the selection, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> wthout <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mac use command instead of control

<kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd> to lowercase

<kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> to uppercase